# Radius of an open ball

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

Show that if $q\in B(x,r)$ and $q\neq x$ then there exists $0<R<d(q,x)$ such that $B(q,R)\subseteq B(x,r)$.

I was wondering as to how to approach it:

Since $B(x,r)$ is  open, there exists a radius $r'>0$ such that $B(q,r')\subseteq B(x,r)$. But this doesn't necessarily mean that $r'\leq r$. I know that there exists an $R$ such that $0<R<d(q,x)$. But otherwise, I'm not sure. I highly suspect that it has to do with $X$ being $T_1$.

Comment: First of all, you can shrink $r’$ as much as you want. Second, $R$ should be less than or equal to  $r-d(q,x)$. Think about the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $0<R<r-d(q,x)$ and conclude by applying the triangle inequality.